# Not save new item in enum to MySQL by using Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I created `enum` in Spring Boot:

```
public `enum` Status implements `EnumText` {
    ACTIVE(`common.active`),
    INACTIVE(`common.inactive`)
    ;
    private String text;
    Status(String text) {`your text`
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

I want to add new item to enum `DELETED("common.deleted")` but when I create new record to MySQL then it throws an error:

> Data truncated for column 'status' at row 1

Is there other solution instead of using query Update in Mysql manually?